# Build a menu in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

main_view

```
<table width="1100" border="1" align="center">
  <tr><?php $this->load->view('header_view'); ?></tr>
  <tr><?php $this->load->view('menu_view'); ?></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"  id="content">
      <?php
            $a = ($_GET['pages/']);
            switch($a)
        {
                case "home":
                  require("pages/home");
                  break;
                case "about":
                  require("pages/about");
                  break;
         }
         ?>
    </td>
    <?php $this->load->view('rightMenu_view'); ?></tr>
  <tr><?php $this->load->view('footer_view'); ?></tr>
</table>
```

menu_view

```
 <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="pages/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/staff">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/chat">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/championat">Championat</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

pages_controller

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('main_view');
    }
    public function home() { echo "Hello"; }
    public function about() { echo "Hello about"; }
}
```

I want to switch to other option in menu and only change the column `td id="content"` with the content. But it doesn't work.

I think the error is at switch.

I did something similar but I have not ever used a framework

Comment: HELP PLIZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it isn't semantic HTML to use tables as a formatting method.  it is best to avoid it.

codeigniter has a $this->input->get('variablename'); which is a bit more secure than $_GET(), and returns FALSE if the GET is not set.

a get call in the URL requires ?name1=value1 in the URL.  you are not using this, which is probably why it is not working.

CI does allow parameters in controller methods. [look into it](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri), you can put the switch in your Pages::index method.